# JTextPane vertical alignment

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

When I use a `JTextPane` I can set the horizontal alignment via HTML:

```
<html><center>my text</center></html>
```

However, does one of you know how I can set vertical alignment? Is it also possible with HTML?

Comment: Read [here](http://java-sl.com/tip_center_vertically.html) about that.

Comment: after that, HTML tags does not work anymore. However I need them

Comment: Is that the *only* text that will appear?  If so, it would be quite simple to do with a `JLabel` using plain text that is centered vertically and horizontally.  AFAIR it was a bit tricky in HTML to center text vertically, especially if there was text after the 'vertically centered' text, and I *strongly* doubt that Java's (very simplistic) implementation of CSS would support it at all.

Comment: *"after that, HTML tags does not work anymore. However I need them"*  Why?  Can you show us a typical 'actual' document that might need it?  And by 'actual' I mean it can use nonsense text (e.g. blocks of [Lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum)) wherever you want, so long as the it *looks* a lot like you are actually needing.  As an aside, can you produce this effect in plain HTML as seen in a browser?  I actually expect that HTML/CSS is not well suited to the task at all.

Comment: I am one step further, but now I get a really strange behaviour: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131748/jtextpane-html-renderer-wrong